# How can i study to operate a dairy spray drying tower?

Tags: drying

I work in a company in the area of spray dryers and I was recently promoted to drying tower operator, previously I was just a production assistant and I still have no training in the area. We have four drying towers focused on drying dairy products, fats and caseinates. We have dryers with the capacity to evaporate 1500, 1200, 600 and 100 kg of water per hour. Everything I learned about operating dryers was purely through practicing and making mistakes, but I wanted to change that, as previously mentioned I still don't have training in the area. Therefore, if someone could help me with study materials on the subject of drying, operation of spray dryers more focused on the dairy sector, I would be grateful. If anyone has had experience operating dryers and could share it with me, I would be grateful. Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... the question must have correct and incorrect answers possible

Comment: your employer should have operating manuals